# Servlet and jsp character encoding idiosyncrasy

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, character-encoding

I have a webapp on which I need to display unicode characters. It's all fine when I write the strings in the jsp, for example:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="com.xyz.foo.ConsoleApp" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body><%= "Setúbal" %></body>
</html>
```

I get the desired output: **Setúbal**

However, the equivalent code in a servlet does not render properly, for example:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    writer.println("<html>");
    writer.println("<head><meta charset='UTF-8'/></head>");
    writer.println("<body>Setúbal</body>");
    writer.println("</html>");
}
```

The same thing happens when in the jsp I load the text from a class:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="com.xyz.foo.ConsoleApp" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body><%= ConsoleApp.getText() %></body>
</html>
```

In both cases I get strange characters: **Set√∫bal**

All files are UTF-8 and the response headers have the following:

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding    gzip
Date    Tue, 09 Nov 2010 09:44:05 GMT
Server  Google Frontend
Cache-Control   private, x-gzip-ok=""
Content-Length  438
```

Comment: `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` is pointless and does nothing since you're already sending the encoding in the content-type http header, and is therefore just confusing and harmful. Remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `javac -encoding` parameter to tell javac what encoding your java source is stored in, otherwise it uses the platform default which apparently isn't UTF-8.

Comment: The .jsp file will be compiled by your web-app server. You might need to check the encoding on your Web-App server as well, if it supports it.

Comment: Yeah, but the jsp files use the pageEncoding attribute in the page header if present, otherwise the charset value of the contentType attribute, in this case specified as UTF-8.

Comment: +1. It's clearly a problem with compiler encoding. Source is stored in UTF-8, when compiler encoding is Mac OS Roman, therefore `ú` -> `C3 BA` -> `√∫`.

Comment: It makes sense, since only the compiled stuff has the error. I'm currently out of home, but I will test it asap.